# chamar um .exe em javaScript ou html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web-service

Estou migrando um sistema desktop para web , com já temos grande parte pronta, gostaria de subir ela e chamar o que ainda não ta pronto da aplicação pelo browser , gostaria de uma ajuda, na seguinte questão qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso, usando angular, javascript puro, html?

Comment: Javascript não tem acesso direto ao disco ou propriedades do sistema, a não ser pelo node.js.

Comment: tem alguma maneira de fazer  um aplicação web service abrir uma aplicação em desktop?

Comment: O que você poderia fazer é uma aplicação back-end (node.js, java, spring, etc) com um end-point que quando consumido executa o seu .exe, e consumir esse end-point da sua aplicação web.

Comment: Procure por URI Handler na linguagem utilizada no seu sistema desktop para saber como registrar URLs do tipo `suaAplicacao:\\dados`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode implementar um URI Handler.

Crie um arquivo .REG a ser executado, com as devidas permissões, nas máquinas Windows, com um conteúdo similar a este:

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SuaAplicacao]
@="URL:Protocolo SuaAplicacao"
"SuaAplicacaoHandler"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SuaAplicacao\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\SuaAplicacao\\SuaAplicacao.exe\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SuaAplicacao\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SuaAplicacao\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\SuaAplicacao\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\SuaAplicacao\\SuaAplicacao.exe\" \"%1\" \"%2\" \"%3\" \"%4\" \"%5\" \"%6\" \"%7\" \"%8\" \"%9\""
```

Após isso, utilize URLs no seguinte formato:

`SuaAplicacaoHandler://qualquerDadoQueDesejarPassar`

para que sua aplicação Windows seja invocada, e o parâmetro `qualquerDadoQueDesejarPassar` recebido pela aplicação.

Comment: valeu OnoSendai

Comment: @Aderbal não por isso, é sempre um prazer ajudar. =)

Answer (score 0):

Não é possível executar arquivos executáveis pelo browser. Por questão de segurança. Já que grande parte do trabalho já foi realizado em sua aplicação desktop. É aconselhado implementar o conceitos de flags na aplicação desktop (passagem de parâmetros) e então consumir este com algumas funções script para disponibilizar os recursos e processamentos através de uma REST API. Assim você poderá utilizar em sua aplicação Web.